# How to make my wallpaper to appear after autologin in lightdm

Tags: openbox, lightdm, wallpaper, autologin, kiosk

These are things I did
 Inside [Seat:*] in

```
/etc/lighdm/lighdm.conf
```

I changed

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
autologin-user=pi
autologin-user-timout=0
```

and in

```
/etc/lighdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

I changed the background to my preferred one by

```
[greeter]
background=/usr/share/pixmaps/splash.png
user-background=/usr/share/pixmaps/splash.png
```

I will see the background wallpaper when autologin is not enabled, but I have to log in manually. When auto login enabled I am logged into the black screen with the mouse and no wallpaper.I want the wallpaper to appear in autologin too.I already spend a lot of time on this.I have tried Openbox without lightdm also using feh.But autologin and startx had to be done manually.As I am not well versed with xinit.I am trying to do it for the kiosk to show a wallpaper before loading time taken by chrome to fetch website.

Answer (score 2):

If `lightdm` is configured with `autologin-user`, it doesn't run any greeter. It immediately opens a session for the given user and hands over to a window manager. Setting your window manager's background should do what you want, e.g. for `openbox` add something similar to:

```
xsetbg /usr/share/pixmaps/splash.png &
```

to your `~/.config/openbox`. Note, that `openbox` must run in session mode, e.g.:

```
$ cat ~/.xinitrc
/usr/bin/openbox-session
```